# How to export my code correctly in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I right-click on my project, then select *Export*, then select *Runnable Jar File* And then *Export*, but when I launch it, it just has a clear screen, but in Eclipse it shows my image.

How would I fix this?

I've tried numerous posts and did everything they said to do, but when I try to put the .jar file in the images folder and then launch the jar it still launches with no background image.

Comment: This is almost certainly because of the way you're loading the image and/or its location in the project... However you've not provided enough detail to know for sure... I recommend you add the image loading code to this question AND the exception shown when your app launches. Try running it from a command prompt using java -jar your-exported.jar

Comment: I'll Try Running It From The Command Line

Comment: i ran it from command prompt and the exception is                                             java.io.FileException: src:\Sounds\Main Menu.wav (The system cannot find the path specified)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  It took me a bit to actually find an answer.  Here is the answer I found.  Save your images in a seperate folder somewhere in your src folder and add to build path.  Then, since the images are static you can just access it like this: blueSprite = ImageLoader.blueSprite;  Don't forget to call ImageLoader.loadImages() too.

```
final public class ImageLoader {

    public static BufferedImage blueSprite;

    public static InputStream load(String path) {
        InputStream input = ImageLoader.class.getResourceAsStream(path);
        if (input==null) {
            input=ImageLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/"+path);
        }
        return input;
    }

public static void loadImages() {
        try {
            blueSprite= ImageIO.read(ImageLoader.load("explosionSheetBlueShort.png"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR LOADING IMAGES.  CONTACT ADMIN FOR SUPPORT");
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This Is Really Weird, When I View My Code On mac OS X There Are A Bunch of Weird Symbols, Ones That Ain't In the Code on My Windows Computer. Have Any Idea?

Comment: Not really.  What does it look like?

Comment: Also there is no music in it but there is music on Eclipse. and its a .wav file so i don't know why i isn't working

Comment: I think i figured out why because in eclipse it's already cd'd into my project where the images folder is but when i ran it outside it was looking at C:\Images\Background which there is no such thing so instead i'd put C:\Blahblahblah/leadingtoimages/background